# merge two dataframes on column with fuzzy match in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes, one for 2008, the other for 2004 and 2012 data. Examples of the dataframes are below.

```
df_08 <- read.table(text = c("
observation     year     x    code_location       location
1               2008     300  23-940 town no. 1   town no. 1   
2               2008     234  23-941 town no. 2   town no. 2    
3               2008     947  23-942 city St 23   city St 23   
4               2008     102  23-943 Mtn town 5   Mtn town 5   "), header = TRUE)

df_04_12 <- read.table(text = c("
observation     year     y    code_location         location
1               2004     124  23-940 town no. 1     town no. 1
2               2004     395  23-345 town # 2       town # 2 
3               2004     1349 23-942 city St 23     city St 23      
4               2012     930  53-443 Mtn town 5     Mtn town 5   
5               2012     185  99-999 town no. 1     town no. 1   
6               2012     500  23-941 town Number 2  town Number 2    
7               2012     185  34-942 city Street 23 city Street 23   
8               2012     195  23-943 Mt town 5      Mt town 5   "), header = TRUE)
```

I want to merge df_08 to df_04_12 using the location variable (the codes are not consistent across years). However, slight variations in the location name, eg Mtn v. Mt or no. v. #, result in no match. Given these slight variations between location names, is there a way to merge these dataframes and get the following? I currently do not have any code for this since I am not sure how to match locations for a merge.

```
observation     year     y    code_location         location.x      location.y    y.y
1               2004     124  23-940 town no. 1     town no. 1      town no.1     300
2               2004     395  "23-345 town # 2"     "town # 2"      "town no. 2"  234
3               2004     1349 23-942 city St 23     city St 23      city St 23    947
4               2012     930  53-443 Mtn town 5     Mtn town 5      Mtn town 5    102   
5               2012     185  99-999 town no. 1     town no. 1      town no. 1    300   
6               2012     500  23-941 town Number 2  town Number 2   town no. 2    234    
7               2012     185  34-942 city Street 23 city Street 23  city St 23    947   
8               2012     195  23-943 Mt town 5      Mt town 5       Mtn town 5    102
```

Comment: Have a look at the **fuzzyjoin** package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use levenshtein distance on character variables but there is no way to account for symbols. I would suggest you clear all of the symbols before merge and than use the stringdist package. There is no clean solution for this problem, you will have to develop your own method as it relates to your data.
Some of the methods that are used in fuzzy matching is string distance calculations and SoundX transformation of the data, you just have to find out what is appropriate for your data.